# how to get model name from tbats function, forecast package in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to get the model arguments from tbats output. 
When I am printing the output as below, the model name with arguments are fully printed in console from "fitted" . But individually I am not able to extract the arguments from fitted.

```
>fitted <- tbats(timeseries)
>fitted
```

When I look into the arguments I find these variables [lambda, alpha, beta, damping.parameter, gamma.one.values, gamma.two.values, ar.coefficients, ma.coefficients, likelihood, optim.return.code, variance, AIC, parameters, seed.states, fitted.values, errors, x, seasonal.periods, k.vector, y, p, q, call, series, method] but not one of them is Omega (box cox transform argument). I can draw the rest of the model from damping.parameter, p, q, seasonal.periods, k.vector.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the model name:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- tbats(USAccDeaths)
as.character(fit)
#> [1] "TBATS(1, {0,0}, -, {<12,5>})"
```

Take a look at the print function to see how it is constructing the output:

```
> forecast:::print.tbats
function (x, ...) 
{
    cat(as.character(x))
    cat("\n")
    cat("\nCall: ")
    print(x$call)
    cat("\nParameters")
    if (!is.null(x$lambda)) {
        cat("\n  Lambda: ")
        cat(round(x$lambda, 6))
    }
    cat("\n  Alpha: ")
    cat(x$alpha)
    if (!is.null(x$beta)) {
        cat("\n  Beta: ")
        cat(x$beta)
        cat("\n  Damping Parameter: ")
        cat(round(x$damping.parameter, 6))
    }
    if (!is.null(x$gamma.one.values)) {
        cat("\n  Gamma-1 Values: ")
        cat(x$gamma.one.values)
    }
    if (!is.null(x$gamma.two.values)) {
        cat("\n  Gamma-2 Values: ")
        cat(x$gamma.two.values)
    }
    if (!is.null(x$ar.coefficients)) {
        cat("\n  AR coefficients: ")
        cat(round(x$ar.coefficients, 6))
    }
    if (!is.null(x$ma.coefficients)) {
        cat("\n  MA coefficients: ")
        cat(round(x$ma.coefficients, 6))
    }
    cat("\n")
    cat("\nSeed States:\n")
    print(x$seed.states)
    cat("\nSigma: ")
    cat(sqrt(x$variance))
    cat("\nAIC: ")
    cat(x$AIC)
    cat("\n")
}
```

Comment: Your way of explaining the codes helps people to dive deeper.